# How to modify files in %username%\AppData

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to modify a file in %appdata%\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment using Powershell.  The script is simply:

```
Add-Content "%appdata%\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\deployment.properties" "mydata"
```

However, it returns "Could not find part of the path 'C:\Users\MyUsername\Desktop\%appdata%\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\deployment.properties"

Even though I specify %appdata%, it's adding in the current directory of the script.  How can I specify the C:\Users\MyUsername\%AppData% folder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So try using the PowerShell environmental variables to do this:

```
Add-Content "$env:appdata\..\locallow\sun\java\deployment\deployment.properties" "mydata"
```

**Edit:** On that note, load up the ISE, type in `$env:` and familiarize yourself with the available environmental variables. It will benefit you in the long run.

Comment: Ooh, didn't know that.  Unfortunately this seems to automatically bring you to Appdata\Roaming.  So now the error is "Could not find part of the path 'C:\users\MyUser\AppData\Roaming\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment'

Comment: Updated answer. To be honest I had `$env:userprofile\appdata\locallow` first but thought better of it. I should have stuck with my gut, but the updated answer works too.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `%appdata%` syntax in PowerShell. Use `$ENV:AppData` in its place:

`Add-Content "$($ENV:AppData)\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\deployment.properties" "mydata"`